# Python re.sub with a string that contains a special character without modifying the string

Tags: python, regex

My problem is that in order to do sub I need to escape a special character. But I don't want to modify the string that I'm substituting. Does Python have way to handle this?

```
fstring = r'C:\Temp\1_file.txt' #this is the new data that I want to substitute in
old_data = r'Some random text\n .*' #I'm looking for this in the file that I'll read
new_data = r'Some random text\n '+fstring  #I want to change it to this
f = open(myfile,'r') #open the file
filedata = f.read() #read the file
f.close()
newfiledata = re.sub(old_data,new_data,filedata) #substitute the new data
```

An error is returned becasue the "\1" in the in "fstring" is seen as a group object.

```
error: invalid group reference
```

Comment: I *think* you may need to escape it in your raw string. Can you try `fstring = r'C:\Temp\\1_file.txt'`?

Comment: Thanks, that works but since I'm reading in lots of files I don't want to have to write extra code to modify each one if I can avoid it. Guess it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape eventual backslashes:

```
new_data = r'Some random text\n ' + fstring.replace('\\', r'\\')
```

Comment: Thanks that is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

`\1` would normally imply a backreference to group 1 of the regex match, but that is not what you intend here (in fact no group 1, which is the reason for the error), you'll, therefore, need to escape the string so `re` does not treat the `\1` as a metacharacter:

```
fstring = r'C:\Temp\\1_file.txt'
```

Comment: I tried that, the problem is that it changesthe string that I'm substituting in: C\:\Temp\NA_CA_logs\1_file\.txt

Comment: @sparrow it does not, try `print`ing the result.

Comment: @sparrow Brainfart on that. There are other metacharacters. You can simply double up the slash so it only escapes `\1`. Answer updated :)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga here is what that looks like: Some random text\n C\:\\Temp\\NA_CA_logs\\\\1_file\.txt

Comment: @MosesKoledoye Thanks, that works but since I'm reading in lots of files I don't want to have to write extra code to modify each one if I can avoid it. Guess it's not a big deal if there is no better way.